# Android listview doesn't get displayed in bottomsheet

Tags: android, listview, bottom-sheet

I want to create a navigational bottom sheet like that in Google Maps Navigational BottomSheet where we have the list of directions for the route. I am using android's BottomSheetBehaviour to open up the bottomsheet. The issue i am currently facing is that the listview doesn't show up inside the bottom sheet layout when it pops up. The view is simply blank. I also tried to inflate view myself inside a NestedScrollView to get the same result, but that too didn't show up.

This is my bottomsheet xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottomSheet1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:paddingRight="20dp"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:background="@color/white"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
android:clipToPadding="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="This is a sheet with listview."
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:text="This is a secondary text!"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nestedLinearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheetListview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And in my java code,

```
View bottomSheetView = findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet1);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetListview);
List<String> listData = getListData(); //returns a simple array list of strings, about 15 items
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listData));
mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetView);
mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Why doesn't the litview or scrollview show up.

[image]

**Edited**
My Whole Activity

```
    public class BottomSheetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final String TAG = "==> BottomSheetActivity";

        BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;
        Button peek;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom_sheet);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            this.peek = (Button) findViewById(R.id.peek);

            peek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    showSheet1();
                }
            });

        }

        private List<String> getListData(){
            List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                stringList.add("This is string number "+i);
            }

            return stringList;
        }

        private void showSheet1(){
            if(mBottomSheetBehavior != null){
                //hide any previous bottom sheets
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
            }
            //initialize a new sheet
            View bottomSheetView = findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet1);

            ListView listView = (ListView) bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetListview);
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            List<String> listData = getListData();
            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listData));

            mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetView);
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }


    }
```

**activity_bottom_sheet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.vedamic.androidtutorial.BottomSheetActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_bottom_sheet" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_sheet_1" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_bottom_shee.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.vedamic.androidtutorial.BottomSheetActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_bottom_sheet">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/peek"
        android:text="peek 1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/expand"
        android:text="peek 2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/flipboardSheet"
        android:text="Flipbard BottomSheets"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/testListView"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe it is because your NestedScrollView has layout_height="match_parent" ?

Comment: I tried setting the NestedScrollView's visibility to GONE and re-ran the application, still same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imported your xml and the android studios "Preview" indeed showed that the `NestedScrollView` with `android:layout_height="match_parent"` takes the whole space so the `ListView` hasn't got space left.

[image]

When setting the `NestedScrollView` to `android:visibility="gone"` the `ListView` has enough space.

[image]

So the only reason now that nothing is shown is maybe because your `listData` is empty?

**EDIT**

OK I implemented all info and the style is very messy. First of all the peek 1 button is behind the toolbar.

[image]

But I can still click it, so this happens:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but i debugged the process and my list data showed 15 items also the adapter's getView() has been called 15 times. The issue persists. Any more ideas how this may have been happening?

Comment: Could you provide the whole code of the Activity class where you add the bottom sheet?

Comment: I imported your activity and all xmls but it looks totally messy... (see my updated answer) but the list view is shown.. somehow

Answer (score 1):

Dont make your listview visibility gone at first. Bottom should know what size it has to be. If you need to make its visibility gone, done it after the bottom sheet created.

And try in your bottom sheet content_bottom_shee.xml parent linearlayout

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```